# Get amount of weekday X in a month

Tags: python, calendar

How do I determine the number of days of weekday X in Python?

E.g. the number of Mondays in September 2014.

Example usage for the standard `0` is Monday, `6` is Sunday calendar scheme:

```
>>> numberOfWeekdays(2014, 9, weekday=0)
5
```

## Edit

Using the accepted answer:

```
def numberOfWeekdays(year, month, weekday=calendar.MONDAY):
    return sum(1 for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year, month) if week[weekday])
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence

Comment: Question edited and improved to negate the reasoning of the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's various ways to do it with [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#module-calendar).  e.g.

```
import calendar

month = (2014, 9) # October, 2014

sum(1 for week in calendar.monthcalendar(*month) if week[calendar.MONDAY])
Out[28]: 5

sum(1 for week in calendar.monthcalendar(*month) if week[calendar.FRIDAY])
Out[29]: 4
```